# spring-boot-starter-data-redis won't work

Tags: spring-boot

I use spring boot 1.4.1, so I have `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` in my

> pom.xml file like this：

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

> This is the main class：

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class).web(true).run(args);
    }
}
```

> This is the  controller class for test：

```
@RestController
public class CommonTestCtrl {
    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template;

    @Autowired
    private StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/redisGet", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getRedisValue(@RequestParam(value = "key", required = false) String key) {
        // not OK
        this.template.opsForValue().set(888888, 188);
        // OK
        this.stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key + "String", "stringRedisTemplate");
        return "";
    }
}
```

I've found that this.template.opsForValue().set(888888, 188); won't save anything to redis. WHY?

Here is the CODE URL: https://github.com/eacdy/test2 .

> Could you help me? THX a lot.

Comment: The code is ok. Nothing is wrong. I missed the data in redis.

Comment: The artifact name changed - it wasn't that you just omitted data, but it used to not have the data.

Comment: link rot on https://github.com/eacdy/test2

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from spring-boot 1.3.7.RELEASE TO 1.5.10.RELEASE.  The artifact name changed from:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

To:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: both OP and me are using spring-boot-starter-data-redis dependency. I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: Agreed - but it was for me, and I found this article in my searches for the errors! Maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code from [spring-boot-data-redis-starter official sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-redis), with a difference:

```
@Autowired
private StringRedisTemplate template;

@Autowired
private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    {
        ValueOperations<String, Integer> stringIntegerValueOperations = this.redisTemplate.opsForValue();
        String key = "hello";
        int v = 100;
        if (!this.redisTemplate.hasKey(key)) {
            System.out.println("write redisTemplate"); // stored in redis.
            stringIntegerValueOperations.set(key, v);
        }
        Set<String> keys = this.redisTemplate.keys("*");
        System.out.println(String.join(",", keys)); // 0 result.
    }
    {
        ValueOperations<String, String> ops = this.template.opsForValue();
        String key = "spring.boot.redis.test";
        if (!this.template.hasKey(key)) {
            ops.set(key, "foo"); // stored in redis server.
            System.out.println("write stringTemplate");
        }
        Set<String> keys = this.template.keys("*"); // all data even ones stored by redisTemplate
        System.out.println(String.join(",", keys));
    }

}
```

At the same time I started a redis CLI to see what `keys *` gives.

**Result**:

1. both templates have their K V stored.
2. `RedisTemplate` stored K (even string) in binary form (mostly not printable)
3. `RedisTemplate hasKey(K)` does give correct result, although `RedisTemplate keys("*")` gives 0 result regardless the type of key (String or binary)
4. StringRedisTemplate keys("*") lists all keys stored in redis.
5. redis CLI stops printing, once it touches a binary item, which means even printable K V after this item would 'hidden'.

**Conclusion**:
`RedisTemplate` no matter which form (`StringRedisTemplate` or raw one： `RedisTemplate`) both having their K V saved in redis server. Although raw `RedisTemplate` keys gives 0 result, and Redis CLI `keys *` stops at first binary K V. Both of these makes it looking like `RedisTemplate` failed to save.

**Solution:**
RedisTemplate stores string K in binary form which is not expected. Like `StringRedisTemplate`, implement a `StringObjectRedisTemplate`  and instead of injecting a raw `RedisTemplate`, use `StringObjectRedisTemplate`.